# Alfresco as repository only: how to organize data?

Tags: java, repository, alfresco

I need to manage attachments on my Spring web application and I thought to use an open source repository. My app it's a job approval system using Java EE / SPRING 3 Framework and postgress DB to allow user to tracks the job, right through every step of the approval process. It is a fully managed, collaborative system that operates from a central server and is accessed by a standard internet browser.

I've a little bit of experience in Alfresco and I'm using it to store data into the repository and I've a doubt about the data organization into the repository. Have I to take care about the organization the data or just upload files into the repository when needed? For instance, I could create a new folder on repository for every request, is it a correct or no?

any suggestion will be really helpful!

thanks in advance, Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no extensive guideline on the repository structure. It really depends on the content you store and its lifecycle. There are countless concerns that might affect your design, for instance:

- you need to configure [rules](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Actions_and_Rules) to handle only some content items -> more folders needed
- you need to configure a [behavior](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Policy_Component) to act on some of the content items (e.g. `cmis:document` to `ws:asset` in the Web [QuickStart](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Developer_Guide#Behaviours))
- you store a gazillion content items -> you must use a balanced tree of folders to keep performance
- you need to configure permissions on subsets of the content items -> easier to configure a folder and let documents inherit

Comment: I like "gazillion" content items :)

Comment: It's exactly what I thought.... put all contents into a single folder could be very bad for performance

Comment: Yes. There are some semi-official numbers going around, in my experience 1k children can be already too much. And if you're connecting via CIFS using MS Explorer, that's simply unusable because of all the prefetch it will attempt.

Comment: @skuro "The 1k children load" issue has hit me ages ago - still got no satisfiying answer. Now took the opportunity and created a new question here. ;)